# Is the Official Fragment Developer Guide Contradicting itself?

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments

In the [Design Philosophy](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design) section of the [official Fragment guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), it says:

> You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity component. That is, because each fragment defines its own layout and its own behavior with its own lifecycle callbacks, you can include one fragment in multiple activities, so you should design for reuse and **avoid directly manipulating one fragment from another fragment**.

But in its [Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example), the `TitlesFragment` class (extends `ListFragment`) is directly referencing the `DetailsFragment` class (extends `Fragment`) in its `showDetails()` method by `findFragmentById()`

```
DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
        getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
```

and calling `DetailsFragment` class's `newInstance()` method.

```
details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);
```

Is it a bad coding style?

Comparatively, the [Basic Training Material](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) seems doing better in coding style. It uses an Interface for Fragment-to-Activity communication.

Comment: I suspect this might just be an artifact of trying to keep the example simple and small.

Comment: i am also thinking about, the first line is just referencing another `Fragment` object, and it has checked-null properly in the following line. For the second one, it is just calling a static method from the class. Without doubt, the way in the Basic Training Material is neater and more well structured. But does these two lines already mean **_manipulating_** the other `Fragment` object?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a bad coding style?

IMHO, yes. IMHO, a fragment should neither know nor care about other fragments managed by the activity. A fragment may care about *nested* fragments (child fragments through `getChildFragmentManager()`), but not possible peer fragments.

In the case of the cited example, `TitlesFragment` should not care whether it is being shown in single-pane or dual-pane mode. The activity should care about that. This isolates all screen-size-dependent code in the activity -- `TitlesFragment` can be oblivious to screen size.

That being said, there's nothing technically wrong with the code AFAIK -- it's just not how I would recommend doing it.